# Google play services android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am trying to use google play services in my library in on e of my android projects.. I went through several posts in this website and according to http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html I did the following.
My build.gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.base"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':robodemolib')
    compile project(':album')
    compile project(':main')
    compile project(':processButtonLibrary')
    compile project(':emptyLayout')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'

}
```

Copied

```
google-play-services.jar
google-play-services.jar.properties
```

to projects lib folder
and added these lines to proguard-project.txt

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

But when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
Gradle 'ViewFindAr_android' project refresh failed
Error:exception during working with external system:
```

Update:
By now the google play services error is vanished ... But I have a different error

```
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher takepic.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/takepic.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher ic_drawer.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher add.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): libpng error: Not a PNG file
    AAPT out(21115097) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher login.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/login.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher ic_drawer.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher add.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): libpng error: Not a PNG file
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher login.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/login.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher ic_drawer.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher menu_dropdown_panel_viewfind.9.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/login.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher add.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): libpng error: Not a PNG file
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher ic_drawer.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher user1.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/user1.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher user2.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/user2.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher takepic.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/takepic.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher add.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): libpng error: Not a PNG file
    AAPT out(16533872) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher ic_drawer.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher takepic.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/takepic.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher login.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/login.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher takepic.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/takepic.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT out(26701134) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png
    AAPT out(26701134) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching single PNG file: /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png
    AAPT out(26701134) : No Delegate set : lost message:    Output file: /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/build/intermediates/res/debug/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png
    AAPT out(26701134) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
    AAPT out(7096594) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/menu_dropdown_panel_viewfind.9.png
    AAPT out(7096594) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching single PNG file: /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/menu_dropdown_panel_viewfind.9.png
    AAPT out(7096594) : No Delegate set : lost message: Output file: /root/AndroidstudioProjects/ViewFindAr_android/viewFindAr_android/build/intermediates/res/debug/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/menu_dropdown_panel_viewfind.9.png
    AAPT out(7096594) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
    :viewFindAr_android:mergeDebugResources FAILED
    Error:Execution failed for task ':viewFindAr_android:mergeDebugResources'.
    > Crunching Cruncher add.png failed, see logs
    Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: but why you added `.jar` in lib ?

Comment: Even though I remove the jar I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need copy 

google-play-services.jar and google-play-services.jar.properties 
in your lib folder.
It is enough to add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

Comment: Rebuild project. Add to your question full text of your build.gradle files. And list of libraries in libs folder.

Comment: I updated my question.. and there are no libraries in libs folder

Comment: @Goutam do you relay need compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19' ? Why not just compileSdkVersion 22?

Comment: By now that error is vanished resulting in a different error

Comment: As i understand now you have problem with resources. You can additionally check build files and resources of your library-projects like robodemolib album etc.